# Only show a segment of the codeText in the live code editor for React Component Playground library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Has anyone tried using the React Component library? https://formidable.com/open-source/component-playground/

Is there a way to only show just a segment of the codeText in the live code editor (e.g without the class and render method) but still setting the noRender to false?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your component and then extend it with another component with the methods and properties you want to show.

For example;

```
export default class PrivateComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // constructor logic here
  }

  someHiddenMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hidden Render</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
import PrivateComponent from './PrivateComponent.jsx';

export default class PublicComponent extends PrivateComponent {
  somePublicMethod() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll give this a try. Thanks a lot!